# OpenCV camera calibration - Intrinsic matrix values are off

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, camera, camera-calibration

I used OpenCV's camera calibration function for calibrating my camera. I captured around 50 images with different angles and pattern near image borders.

Cx and Cy value in intrinsic matrix is around 300 px off. Is it alright? My average reprojection error is around 0.08 though.

Answer (score 0):

Cx and Cy are the coordinates (in pixels) of the principal point in your image. Usually a good approximation is (image_width/2, image_height/2).

An average reprojection error of 0.08 pixel seems quite good.

Comment: I have repeated the calibration process multiple times. Cx and Cy are not close to half of image width and height. How do these values affect extrinsic matrix computation?

Comment: Cx and Cy are part of the intrinsic parameters. What kind of extrinsic calibration are you doing ?

Comment: I need to covert the image points to real world coordinates. So, for that I have a separate grid and I'm going find a matrix which will convert image points to real world points.

Comment: The intrinsic parameters relates image points to 3D rays (with RGB cameras you don't have the depth of these points). So, if your Cx and Cy are wrong, the 3D ray that correspond to a certain point in the image will be wrong. How far are Cx and Cy from W/2 and H/2 ? and are you using a very specific camera or just a standard one ?